# Cannot see why a controller method with 2 date parameters doesnt work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have a really strange and frustrating issue

I have a controller with a standard Web Api Controller

```
[Route("Gateway/[Controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController: Controller
{
    public MyController()
    {
    }

    [ActionName("MyMethod")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethodAsync(int numberParam, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {

        var parameters = $"numberParam={numberParam}";
        if (startDate != null)
        {
            parameters += $"&startDate={startDate.Value:O}";
        }

        if (endDate != null)
        {
            parameters += $"&endDate={endDate.Value:O}";
        }

//My logic here - not relevant for question

        return result;
    }
}
```

When I call my method with the parameters

```
?numberParam=1&startDate=01/01/2018&endDate=31/01/2018
```

endDate comes through as null

Why is this?

There are no errors, I have no idea why the second parameter is being ignored

This applies regardless of the date format?

I dont need times

This occurs when using the full url eg http://mysite/GatewayController/MyMethod?numberParam=1&startDate=01/01/2018&endDate=31/01/2018

I also call this through a HttpClient, which doesnt work either

```
private static async Task<string> ProcessResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return responseText;
    }

    return "Error: " + response.StatusCode + " Content: " + responseText;
}

 private static string GetUrl(string area, string method, string parameters)
 {
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
   {
     if (parameters[0] != '?')
     {
       parameters = $"?{parameters}";
     }
   }

   var address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GatewayUrl"];
   var result = $"{address}/{area}/{method}{parameters}";            
   return result;
}

protected async Task<string> ExecuteRequestAsync(string area, string method, string parameters)
{                        
   var url = GetUrl(area, method, parameters);            
   var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
   var result = await ProcessResponseAsync(response).ConfigureAwait(false);

   return result;
}
```

Paul

Comment: Could you show the code that calls this method? Using Ajax or Action?

Comment: See description

Comment: Could you try to change 31/01/2018 to the different value? For example: 02/02/2018.

Comment: Try with different startDate like http://mysite/GatewayController/MyMethod?numberParam=1&startDate=01/02/2018&endDate=31/01/2018. Then check that whether startDate contains value as 1st February or 2nd January?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the url without special charater "/", by replacing "/" with "-"
?numberParam=1&startDate=01-01-2018&endDate=31-01-2018

OR
Encode the special characters with,

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: Thanks I also needed to pass date through as yyyy-mm-dd as UK date was being treated as USA date